# displaying a flash message after redirect

Tags: extension

I'm programming an EE extension, and in the `save_settings()` method, if I `redirect()` (after unsuccessful data validation), the message stored in the `set_flashdata()` method doesn't show.
 If I comment the redirect and let the method put the user back in the main extensions page, then the flashdata shows up fine. It's *only* if I redirect that the data isn't shown.

This is my save settings method - as near as I can tell I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary - it's mostly boilerplate as near as I can tell. I'd be very appreciative of anybody that can shed light on this...

```
function save_settings(){

    // no unauthorized access
    if (empty($_POST)) {
        show_error($this->EE->lang->line('unauthorized_access'));
    }

    // get the routestring then convert it to an array
    $routestring = $this->EE->security->xss_clean($this->EE->input->post('routes'));
    $results = $this->routes_to_array($routestring);

    // if the conversion was ok:
    if ($results['status'] == 'success') {

        // update db
        $this->EE->db->where('class', __CLASS__);
        $this->EE->db->update('extensions', array('settings' => serialize(array('routes' => $results['results']))));

        // set flash data
        $this->EE->session->set_flashdata('message_success', "Routes updated.");

    // if something went wrong during conversion:  
    } else {

        // set flash data then redirect back to edit screen
        $this->EE->session->set_flashdata('message_failure', $results['message']);

        // IF I COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE, THE FLASH DATA SHOWS UP FINE
        $this->EE->functions->redirect(BASE.AMP.'C=addons_extensions'.AMP.'M=extension_settings'.AMP.'file=apsdsm_bossyboots');
    }              
}
```

OK, this is my view file - as far as I can tell this is as boiler plate as it gets. More boiler plate than a dish that's been held in scalding water for ten minutes.

```
<?php echo form_open('C=addons_extensions'.AMP.'M=save_extension_settings'.AMP.'file=apsdsm_bossyboots'); ?>

<table class="mainTable" border="0"cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Routes
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>

                <?php echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'routes', 'value' => $routestring)) ?>

                <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Update Routes', 'class="submit"') ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php echo form_close()?>
```

Comment: I think something else is going on here. That is almost exactly the same code I've used many times. Can you check Chrome/Firebug Network tab and make sure there aren't any stray redirects occurring?

Comment: OK: so I checked the Network data: the only redirect going on there is the one in my code, and it looks like the `ext_flash` cookie is being set correctly - I can see the correct error data being passed along in the headers, but it's not displaying...

Comment: Sorry, not `ext_flash`, I meant `exp_flash`.

Comment: What method you using to display the flash data?

Comment: I'm just letting the Expression Engine control panel take care of it - So, after the redirect I'm not including any special code in my 'save_settings' method or anything. I swear I've done that before and it's worked fine...

Comment: I wonder if there's something in the view file for your extension settings screen that's causing an error, thus preventing the flash message from displaying? Your code looks correct to me.

Comment: I'll update my question with the contents of my view file. The view file is also very boilerplate, but maybe some fresh eyes can shed light on this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a link to the full source of your plugin so far so we can try it locally?

Comment: The beta code is on my git hub account at https://github.com/apsdsm/bossyboots - I thought I left this link here the other day, but turns out I didn't. Guess that'll show me to rely on my 3G connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive if this will work or not, but the CodeIgniter Session library has a method for keeping flashdata for more more request, I'd imagine this would help here.

Try adding this before the redirect: `$this->EE->session->keep_flashdata('message_failure');`

Comment: Unfortunately, though that method is declared in the CI lib, it doesn't seem to be in the EE version... Flags an undefined error message... Thanks for the suggestion though, I appreciate it!