# set_flashdata with save_settings for extensions

Tags: add-on-development, extension

After saving an extension's settings, EE by default redirects you to the Extensions landing page. I want to keep the user in the extension settings after saving but also use EE's flashdata.

The below code is in my save_settings method.

```
$this->EE->session->set_flashdata('message_success', $this->EE->lang->line('preferences_updated'));
$this->EE->functions->redirect(BASE.AMP.'C=addons_extensions'.AMP.'M=extension_settings'.AMP.'file=my_custom_extension');
```

Does anyone know why set_flashdata does not seem to work after the redirect where in Module settings this does?

I've also looked into this help request: [displaying a flash message after redirect](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2155/displaying-a-flash-message-after-redirect)

Comment: Shot in the dark - try an `exit()` after your redirect?

Answer (score 1):

To do that you'll have to, I think, create the custom settings form for the extension. Once you have that, you'll also have to run custom processing so you'll have complete control of the redirect. Take a look at the [extension docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html#settings) for details. For a complete example, take a look at the EE Debug Toolbar settings code.